# RabbitMQ Quorum queue per message expiration not working

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Per the RabbitMQ [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/ttl#message-ttl-dead-lettering), the new Quorum queues should handle per message expiration as it happens instead of waiting for the message to get to the head of the queue.

I've made a setup to test this with the following arguments on my queue:

```cs
var QuorumQueueArguments = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "x-dead-letter-exchange", "MyExchangeName" },
    { "x-queue-type", "quorum" }
};
```

From my manual testing, the behavior is the same as the normal queues. It waits for the message to get to the head of the queue. Am I missing something or is it a bug?

**EDIT:**

It turns out that the rabbitmq documentation was not up-to-date and the quorum queues don't have a different behavior concerning per message expiration in queues.